# Fetch secret from Vault when initializing next.js

Tags: next.js, auth0, hashicorp-vault

I'm using next.js with the library https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/

To initialise that library I need to fetch a secret from Vault using async/await but I get a `Promise { <pending> }`

I would have thought the following would work:

```js
// utils/auth0.js

import { initAuth0 } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
const vault = require('./vault');

async function getSecretFromVault() {
  const res = await vault.fetchSecret();
  console.log(res);  // shows my secret correctly
  return res;
}

const secret = getSecretFromVault();
console.log(secret);  // shows Promise { <pending> }

export default initAuth0({
  clientId: "my_ID",
  clientSecret: secret  // this will be invalid: UI shows "client_id is required"
  ....
});
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `async` method returns a **promise**, you should use `await` in order to get the async data.

Since module export is a **sync** it is better to export an **async** method which will make your call to Vault and return the initialization of Auth0.

```js
// utils/auth0.js

import { initAuth0 } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
const vault = require('./vault');

async function getSecretFromVault() {
  const res = await vault.fetchSecret();
  console.log(res); // shows my secret correctly
  return res;
}

let instance;

async function getAuth0() {
  if(instance) {
    return Promise.resolve(instance);
  }
  
  const secret = await getSecretFromVault();
  // -------------^
  instance = initAuth0({
    clientId: 'my_ID',
    clientSecret: secret, // this will be invalid: UI shows "client_id is required"
  });
  
  return instance;
}

export default getAuth0;
```

```js
// usage

import getAuth0 from './utils/auth0';

export default async function login(req, res) {
  const auth0 = await getAuth0();
  // --------------------^ get instance
  try {
    await auth0.handleLogin(req, res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(error.status || 400).end(error.message);
  }
}
```